# Using Microsoft Bot Framework, how to login to my website from a Slack channel, then comeback to the bot as a connected person ? (Node)

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, bots, botframework, slack-api

Currently my users are using a Messenger channel. They use linking_account from Messenger, described here: https://blog.vjrantal.net/2016/11/15/facebook-account-linking-with-microsoft-bot-framework/

So when they click on login in the bot, they automatically go to my website, enter credentials, click on login then the window closes and they are back to the bot.
It works pretty well.

I am using:

```
if (session.message.sourceEvent.account_linking) {
   ...
}
```

To know if there is an account_linking event happening and it works, I can login, but... I don't really know how it works behind. Can I listen to events from Slack or something ?

Finally, how can I achieve the same thing using Slack ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but can you clarify what you mean by "listen to events from Slack" please?

Comment: I didn't find out how to do it yet. Fortunately, it's far on the roadmap :)
When I said 'listen to events from Slack', I mean a bit like this one: `sourceEvent.account_linking` but from Slack, so if it's possible on this platform